# Creating Multiple FK Relationships using CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

In my schema design, I have 2 tables that are related by 2 different keys. I know how EF magically creates foreign keys when they are the "Id" members of the table but what I don't quite understand is how to create a 2nd relationship.

NOTE: This schema does not actually exist yet; I am going to use codefirst to create it.

Here is a simple diagram of what I am trying to do (the relationship in pink is the one I am not sure about how to implement in codefirst) NewClub.Id is a primary key and all of the NEW_CLUB_ID are a foreign key to it The pink-highlighted columns are related but not unique:
[image]

```
    namespace NCB.Models
    {
     public  sealed class NewClub
     {


        public NewClub()
        {
            //Related tables here
            NewClubRecruitingTeams = new List<NewClubRecruitingTeam>();
            NewClubRecruitingTeamDates = new List<NewClubRecruitingTeamDate>();

        }

        //Primary Key
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //Club Info
        public string CreatorMasterCustomerId { get; set; }
        public string ClubMasterCustomerId { get; set; }
        public bool IsConverted { get; set; }
        public string NewClubName { get; set; }
        public string NewClubLocation { get; set; }
        public string NewClubType { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }


        // Related tables here
        public virtual List<NewClubRecruitingTeam> NewClubRecruitingTeams { get; set; }
        public virtual List<NewClubRecruitingTeamDate> NewClubRecruitingTeamDates { get; set; }

     }

     public class NewClubRecruitingTeamDate
    {
        //Primary Key
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //Foriegn Keys
        public int NewClubId { get; set; }
        public int NewClubRecruitingTeamTeamNumber { get; set; }

        public DateTime? StartDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }

        public NewClub NewClub { get; set; }
        public NewClubRecruitingTeam NewClubRecruitingTeam { get; set; }
    }

     public class NewClubRecruitingTeam
    {
        //Primary Key
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //Foreign Key
        public int NewClubId { get; set; }

        public int TeamNumber { get; set; }
        public string TeamMemberName { get; set; }
        public string TeamMemberEmail { get; set; }
        public string TeamMemberPhone { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }

        public NewClub NewClub { get; set; }


      }
   }
```

Comment: I really like your drawing.

Comment: Is this an existing DB schema and one of the pink columns is unique? You can't create a relationship (with navigation properties etc.) with EF for this schema because there is no support of unique constraints. A primary key must always be involved in a relationship. Unrelated side note: The `sealed` keyword for your `NewClub` class will prevent lazy loading to work properly.

Comment: @Slauma Thanks for the lazy loading heads-up. I updated my question to address your questions